# Git: pulling from forked repo and pushing to my fork

Tags: git, github

I have forked a git repo (call it upstream) and I have a forked copy of it on my github (call it origin) , and I have a local copy of the fork on my machine. I want to keep my fork up to date with the original repo.

The project has several branches, and I might be working on any of them in a given day. I check out my local copy of branch, and I want to update it with the latest changes from upstream/branch, and then push those changes to origin/branch so that everything is up to date.

Is there a way to set a branch to pull from remote but push to origin? I can do it now by manually setting the tracked branch to upstream/branch, doing git pull, then manually setting the tracked branch to origin/branch and doing git push. This works, but it seems very clumsy. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion, usually your personal fork would be called "origin" and the original repo is called "upstream". Sometimes I name my personal fork "personal"

Comment: Thanks, I have edited to be consistent with this convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO in situations like this I prefer my `push` and `pull` statements to be explicit, even if it's a bit more typing.

For example, rather than relying on things like tracking branches, I will use the form:

```
git push|pull <remote> <branch>
```

Example:

```
# pull from remote
git pull remote master

# push to origin
git push origin master
```

This way, I am confident that I've pulled/pushed from/to the correct location.

If this seems like too much typing, you could always define an alias:

```
git config --global alias.pullr "pull remote master"
git config --global alias.pusho "push origin master"
```

and invoke those aliases like this:

```
git pullr
git pusho
```

After running those `git-config` commands, you can edit your aliases in your `~/.gitconfig` file.

Comment: `git remote --help` concurs with this. 
 "Note that the push URL and the fetch URL, even though they can be
 set differently, must still refer to the same place. What you
 pushed to the push URL should be what you would see if you
 immediately fetched from the fetch URL. If you are trying to fetch
 from one place (e.g. your upstream) and push to another (e.g. your
 publishing repository), use two separate remotes."

Answer (score 0):

While I also typically use Jonathan's approach, the way you accomplish what you describe in the question is:

`git remote set-url --push REMOTE_NAME URL_OF_ORIGIN_FORK`

For example if your remote is named "upstream", you would say:

`git remote set-url --push upstream URL_OF_ORIGIN_FORK`

This will make `git push` send changes to "origin" and `git pull` will grab changes from "upstream".